# CSS and Index.cshtml seem not to be connected in my MVC Application. Any ideas why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a blog with MVC, but somehow my link between my CSS in Content and my Views->Home->Index.cshtml is not working quite right. A coouple of times the changes, which are supposed to happen are seen for a blink of an eye moment and then gone - and nothing seems to get changed on my blog. Mostly it seems not to work.

Thing is, I am using the following code in CSS:

```
.post>h2, .post>div{

    color: red;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

and I do have a corresponding post class in my Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="post col-md-6">
        <h2 class="title">Post title</h2>
        <div class="about">
            Posted on <i>29-Nov-2016</i> by <i>Dinyo Donchev(donchev)</i>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            Here goes post content...
        </div>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?         
        LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
```

So I thought this is supposed to be legit and flawless and work, but somehow that is not the case.

Any ideas on how I can fix this.

Thank you very much in advace. Hope there wasn't the exact same question already existing somewhere on the site, because I failed to see it. If there was - sorry for losing your time and making irrelevant posts.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following line to the head of your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
```

You have to change "stylesheet.css" to your file name certainly.
Then it should work.

I hope this is, what you want to know.

Comment: @user7236339 could you rate this answer?

Comment: Dude, I tried, but I am new and it said that the upvote of a user beneath 15 reputaion is considered/counted, but somehow not giving any points. If I undestood it right, in order for my upvotes to add points to peoples reputation, I need to have at least 15 reputation myself(I registered today, so I have 1 :D). But still, you helped me alot, thanks.